# Restricting duplicate values in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I need to restrict users entering duplicate values in the columns 2 and 5 compared to the columns 2 and 5 in a previous row

My code restricts entering duplicates if either Column 2 OR Column 5 has duplicates compared to the values for these columns in a previous row.

My goal is to have a warning / action when both columns have duplicate values.

Screenshot example:
[image]

VBA code in "Sheet1":

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If (.Column <> 2 And .Column <> 5) Or .Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Columns(.Column), .Value) > 1 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .ClearContents
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            MsgBox "Duplicate value!"
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, better clarify what "if BOTH columns are duplicates" should mean. Should it be interpreted as "if the target value already exists once  in each these both columns" ?

Comment: @FaneDuru Sorry, "if BOTH columns are duplicates"  = if the values entered in column 2 and in column 5 are the same values as in previous row - for these two columns

Comment: Your event code does not allow simultaneous entering in those columns. `.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` stops the code. It should be necessary to better explain what you try accomplishing. In your question you ask about duplicates, now you talk about the "previous row"... Did you want saying previous **rows**?  Meaning existing values in those two columns? Even so, you should be better clarifying what what you want. I must confess that I still not understand what you really need... Where my above interpretation suggestion is wrong? I mean, in my first comment...

Comment: @FaneDuru plz see my updated post

Comment: OK. Clearer a little... 1. How many cells does `Target` contain?  I mean isn't only one cell modified (column B **OR** E)?. 2. If only one cell, but it must be checked against both columns, **should it check only the row above the one where the `Target` exists**? 3. Should the event allow a `Targed` consisting of a discontinuous range with two cells (`Range("B3, E3")`)? If not the row above to be the reference, your example in not so elocvent...

Comment: @FaneDuru 1. I am not sure I understood this question. I modify column B and E (no columns should be empty)  2. yes - it should check only the row above the one where Target exists  3 yes (again if I understood it correctly)

Comment: So, do you **simultaneously modify B and E**? This is not allowed by the above code... It restricts `Target` to contain only one cell. Are you sure about this statement? In fact, how do you simultaneous modify those two cells? Manually, by using a macro?

Comment: Anyhow, `Target.Value` cannot be used in the way your code does, if it is a matter of a multi cells `Target` range. You should try better understand what you are doing and after that how you explain it to us, in order to better understand what you try accomplishing...

Comment: Is this a theme received from somebody else? Are you sure that the cells in discussion aren't changed **one by one** and each time the condition of not duplicating the previous row in B and E is checked? I am still waiting for an answer at the clarification question "how do you simultaneous modify those two cells?"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Find, FindNext on column 2 and then check the value in column 5. Note - this will find duplicate in any row not just the previous.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const PK1 = 2 ' Primary Keys
    Const PK2 = 5

    Dim V1, V2, rng As Range, first As String
    
    If (Target.Column = PK1) Or (Target.Column = PK2) Then
        V1 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, PK1) ' B
        V2 = Me.Cells(Target.Row, PK2) ' E
        If V1 = "" Or V2 = "" Then Exit Sub
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With Me.Columns(PK1)
        Set rng = .Find(V1, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            first = rng.Address
            Do
               If (rng.Row <> Target.Row) And (Cells(rng.Row, PK2) = V2) Then
                  MsgBox "Duplicate Value " & V1 & "," & V2, vbExclamation, "Row " & rng.Row
                  Target.Select
                  Application.EnableEvents = False
                  Target.Clear
                  Application.EnableEvents = True
                  Exit Do
               End If
               Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
            Loop While rng.Address <> first
         End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```